# JLabel not updating when button is pressed

Tags: java, jpanel, jbutton, jlabel

Making a calculator for a final, having difficulties having my JLabel update.  When the Label initializes, it displays the start value of `opNum` just fine, however whenever the method is called to add a number to the end of `opNum`, it doesnt seem to update.  I'm not sure if it isnt repainting, or if something is going wrong when I call the method from the button. I'm doing something stupid or bad, or both.  Help?

JLabel and Methods class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class NumberText extends JPanel
{
private JLabel opNumLabel;
private String opNum;
private double storeNum = 0;
private boolean firstOp = true;
private char op;
private char sign = '+';

//Panel for Number
public NumberText()
{
    //I heard that it could be an issue with the Label not having enough space, though this didnt help
    opNumLabel = new JLabel ("1234567890111");
    opNumLabel.setText(opNum);
    add(opNumLabel);
    setPreferredSize (new Dimension (150, 40));
    setBackground (Color.white);
}

//Clears the current typed number
public void Clear ()
{
    opNum = "";
    opNumLabel.setText(opNum);
}

//Sets it back to conditions like the start of the program
public void ClearAll ()
{
    opNum = "";
    storeNum = 0;
    firstOp = true;
    opNumLabel.setText(opNum);
}


//for storing the operation
public void OpStore (char newOp)
{
    op = newOp;
    firstOp = false;
}

//for adding to the opNum
public void Edit (String button)
{
    opNum = opNum + button;
    opNumLabel.setText(opNum);
    opNumLabel.repaint();
}

//for testing for the first Operation
public boolean IsFirstOp ()
{
    return firstOp;
}

//for changing the sign
public void SignChange ()
{
    if (sign == '+')
    {
        opNum = "-" + opNum;
        opNumLabel.setText(opNum);
        sign = '-';
    }

    else if (sign == '-')
    {
        opNum.replaceAll("-", "");
        opNumLabel.setText(opNum);
        sign = '+';
    }
}

//for storing a number when an operation is pressed
public void StoreNum ()
{
    storeNum = Double.parseDouble(opNum);
    opNum = "";
}

//Math when an Operation is to be done
public void Operation()
{
    double value = Double.parseDouble(opNum);
    double total = 0;

    switch(op)
    {
        case '+': total = storeNum + value;
            break;

        case '-': total = storeNum - value;
            break;

        case '/': total = storeNum / value;
            break;

        case '*': total = storeNum * value;
            break;

        case '%': total = storeNum % value;
            break;
    }

    opNum = Double.toString(total);
    opNumLabel.setText(opNum);
}


}
```

Button Example:

```
public class Button1 extends JPanel
{
private JButton push;
private JLabel label;
public Button1 ()
{

  push = new JButton ("1");
  push.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());

  add (push);
}
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
  {
      //to avoid non-static cant be ref by static
     NumberText NumberText = new NumberText();
     NumberText.Edit("1");
  }
}
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't start the names of your methods with an uppercase letter.

Comment: Also, shouldn't your Button1 class extend JButton instead of JPanel?

Comment: Not sure why but when I put it as JButton, the button is enormous and looks weird.  So ive left it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `actionPerformed(...)` you're editing `NumberText.Edit("1")` a new `NumberText` which is not added to any frame. If you want the changes that you make in the `Edit(...)` method to take effect, you need to get a reference to the `NumberText` that is already displayed.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    ....
    NumberText numberText = new NumberText();
    Button1 button = new Button1(numberText);
    JPanel pan = new JPanel();
    pan.add(numberText);
    pan.add(button);
    frame.add(pan);
    .....
}


public class Button1 extends JPanel {
    private JButton push;
    private JLabel label;
    NumberText alreadyDisplayed;
    public Button1 (NumberText alreadyDisplayed) {
        this.alreadyDisplayed = alreadyDisplayed;
        push = new JButton ("1");
        push.addActionListener (new ButtonListener());
        add(push);
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
            alreadyDisplayed.Edit("1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please forgive me, I'm stressing out because this is due tomorrow and I'm still relatively new to Java, could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: You're literally a hero to me right now.  My only issue is now when the button is pressed for the first time, it displays null as well as 1.  but THANK YOU

Comment: @PatrickDonny I'm glad I could help, to fix the `null` problem just initialize the `opNum` variable from the `NumberText` class, eg: `private String opNum = "";`.